# dot42 WebClient.DownloadString error even have permission

Tags: android, dot42

I am using dot42 to develop android app, but it keeps error when hitting the line DownloadString

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using Android.App;
using Android.Os;
using Android.Widget;
using Dot42;
using Dot42.Manifest;

[assembly: Application("innosia.com")]
**[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.INTERNET)]**
[assembly: Dot42.FreeAppsKey("##censored##")]
namespace innosia.com
{
    [Activity]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstance);
            SetContentView(R.Layouts.MainLayout);

            var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(R.Ids.MyText);

            List<string> titles = GetTitles();

            textView.SetText(string.Join(",", titles));
        }

        public List<string> GetTitles()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            **var data = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.sorainnosia.com/animea");**
            string[] temps = data.TagMatch("<td><a href=\"javascript:Submit(", "</a>");
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            foreach (string str in temps)
            {
                string t = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("\">") + 2);
                result.Add(t);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The bold line will cause error but VS won't be able to show the error details, I already add UsePermission Internet but it still gave error, anyone know why?

Comment: I also faces the similar issue and decided to move on from dot42

Answer (score 0):

I did not try it but you probably need permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE as well.